# Factorize $a^2x(2−x)[2−ax(2−x)]−x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to factorise this expression:

$a^2x(2-x)[2-ax(2-x)] - x = 0$

I'm aware that:
$a^2x(1-x)[1-ax(1-x)]-x=0$, factorises to: $x[ax-(a-1)][a^2x^2-a(a+1)x+(a+1)]=0$,

but I can't achieve a similar looking result, any suggestions?

Comment: Tip: Expand the expression.

Comment: I have expanded it but cannot achieve 3 brackets like the example has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding and factoring or even cancelling terms can be tedious.
I trust we already know about theory here so it's OK to use tools to cheat.

When in doubt you can [expand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+a%5E2x%282-x%29%5B2-ax%282-x%29%5D+-+x) terms with
Wolfram Alpha and then turn around and
[factor](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+-a%5E3+x%5E4+%2B+4+a%5E3+x%5E3+-+4+a%5E3+x%5E2+-+2+a%5E2+x%5E2+%2B+4+a%5E2+x+-+x+) the result.

$$a^2x(2-x)[2-ax(2-x)] - x\\
=-a^3 x^4 + 4 a^3 x^3 - 4 a^3 x^2 - 2 a^2 x^2 + 4 a^2 x - x\\
=-x (a x - 2 a + 1) (a^2 x^2 - 2 a^2 x - a x + 2 a + 1)
 = 0$$

or you can factor the original expression as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+a%5E2x%282-x%29%5B2-ax%282-x%29%5D+-+x).

$$-x (a x - 2 a + 1) (a^2 x^2 - 2 a^2 x - a x + 2 a + 1)=0$$